# Ember update property on the changes in array

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have following in my controller, and facing issue while updating property with array change..

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  imageIds: Object.keys(JSON.parse(localStorage.image_ids || "{}")),
  // imageIds = ['gnffffffffjdf', 'hzfyfsidfulknm', 'euriekjhfkejh']

  previewImageId: function() {
    return this.imageIds.get('firstObject');
  }.property('imageIds.[]'),

  actions: {
    addDetails: function() {
      this.transitionToRoute('items.add_item');
    },

    removeImage: function(image_id) {
      var uploaded = JSON.parse(localStorage.image_ids || "{}");
      delete uploaded[image_id]
      localStorage.image_ids = JSON.stringify(uploaded);
      this.get("imageIds").removeObject(image_id);
      // this.set("imageIds", Object.keys(JSON.parse(localStorage.image_ids || "{}")));
    },

    updatePreview: function(image_id){
      this.set("previewImageId", image_id);
      var uploaded = JSON.parse(localStorage.image_ids || "{}");
      uploaded[image_id] = image_id;
      localStorage.image_ids = JSON.stringify(uploaded);
      // this.set("imageIds", Object.keys(JSON.parse(localStorage.image_ids)));
      this.get("imageIds").pushObject(image_id);
    }
  },

init: function(){
    var controller = this;

    Ember.$('body').on('click', ".current_image", function() {
      var public_id = Ember.$(this).attr('id');
      controller.set("previewImageId", public_id);
    });
  }

});
```

Whenever there is any change in the `imageIds` array, `previewImageId` should be updated.
tried using `pushObject, removeObject, .get and .set` options.
But still no luck

Can anyone pls help me?

---

ANSWER:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({

  imageIds: function() {
    return Object.keys(JSON.parse(localStorage.image_ids || "{}"));
  }.property(),

  previewImageId: function() {
    return this.get("imageIds.firstObject");
  }.property('imageIds.[]'),

  actions: {
    addDetails: function() {
      this.transitionToRoute('items.add_item');
    },

    removeImage: function(image_id) {
      var uploaded = JSON.parse(localStorage.image_ids || "{}");
      delete uploaded[image_id]
      localStorage.image_ids = JSON.stringify(uploaded);
      this.get("imageIds").removeObject(image_id);
    },

    updatePreview: function(image_id){
      var uploaded = JSON.parse(localStorage.image_ids || "{}");
      uploaded[image_id] = image_id;
      localStorage.image_ids = JSON.stringify(uploaded);
      this.get("imageIds").unshiftObject(image_id);
    }
  },

  init: function(){
    var controller = this;

    Ember.$('body').on('click', ".current_image", function() {
      var public_id = Ember.$(this).attr('id');
      controller.get("imageIds").removeObject(public_id);
      controller.get("imageIds").unshiftObject(public_id);
    });
  }
});
```

Here previously I tried with setting value to previewImageId.. which was wrong way, as it overrides my computed property.

Comment: Why would `previewImageId` change? You are pushing, which places the new item at the end of the array. http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ArrayController.html#method_pushObject

Comment: You might be looking to `unshift` http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ArrayController.html#method_unshiftObject

Comment: here i have an array imageIds (for ex. ['fghkj', 'hfgj', 'dfgjhg'])
and previewImageId is the first element from above array..
On click event, value of previewImageId changes, and i have removed that value from array so i want the value of previewImageId to change as this value is not exist in imageIds array..

This is my requirement, but here the value of previewImageId does not change..(i have updated code snippet at the end)

Comment: @Swati You can set values on the cp. But you should make sure that the cp is setter aware

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could see that you are setting the `previewImageId` cp in a couple of places. You should make the computed property as a `setter` and `getter` aware.

[Take a look here for an example](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v1.6.1/packages_es6/ember-metal/lib/computed.js#L154-L171)

If the cp is implemented without a setter, then setting some value on the cp will overwrite its computed function.

Comment: Awesome.. nice catch..

I would add the answer in question below..

Thanks once again..!!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working [demo](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/yumaculu/1/edit) for your use case.

Basically I made the imageIds a property. Here is the code snippet:

```
App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({

  imageIds: function() {
    return this.get("content");
  }.property(),

  previewImageId: function() {
    return this.get("imageIds").get("firstObject");
  }.property("imageIds.[]"),

  actions: {
    remove: function(item) {
      this.get("imageIds").removeObject(item);
    }
  }
});
```

Hope this helps!